# How can you create a ROLE which isn't allowed to do anything?

Tags: postgresql, role

I want to create a role which by default isn't allowed to do anything. It has basically zero permissions. Starting from such role, I want to grant the minimal set of permissions.

How can you make a role without any kind of permissions?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html

Comment: `create role no_privs;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
CREATE ROLE foo;
```

Be aware of default privileges (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).